# Should each user get his own database user/password when they use a single app?

Tags: mysql, database, security, database-design, odbc

What I am trying to ask is  ...

Users will only ever access the database via my application. The application itself allows an admin user to create/modify/delete users and give them certain privileges. So, I have a table which contains each users log-in name & password.

I am still developing the app, so it currently logs in as root with no password. Obviously, I will change that, but what's the best practise? Should I have a single database user & password which the application uses, or should I create a separate user for the databaase each time a user for the application is created (or modified)? The latter seems like more work.

Comment: a different database user/password per application role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to create a database login for each user.  It's really your app that's interacting with the database, not the user.  Creating extra logins just makes your database that much less secure.

Comment: Thanks the way I have thought about it. I was just curious if it went against received wisdom. Thanks

Comment: -1 it is not common practice, but it has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Comment should have read, It is not common practice ---to use native database logins-- but it has nothing to do with security.

Comment: @Ken Downs - I disagree.  However, I really don't feel like debating the issue.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: I don't really undestand, why not debating the issue? That would be the most interesting part: you could explain why you feel like it makes a database less secure that there are more users - do you mean this way there are more opportunities to "guess"? I don't really think there are capacities to use bruteforce methods to break a database... As it's an accepted answer, I think you could extend it with a little explanation at least. I'm really curious about the reasons, because this could be constructive. Thanks!

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - Jay wrote a very nice answer on the topic.  In retrospect, it probably won't per se increase your security risk - however, having to manage the extra database logins would require a fair amount of extra code; if done wrong, you could easily create security holes.  Particularly if you're planning to rely on database table-level permissions for each user.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: yes, I saw Jay's post, I voted it up. I don't agree with your opinion, because you can even create a huge security hole with just one user enabled. On the other side, even if you have thousands of users, this doesn't necessarily mean that you need "extra codes" to handle the login for them... you can write the code and create a form or anything else you need just once and then substitute usernames or passwords in the appropriate places (user login check could be written just once too). Or maybe we just misunderstand each other. But more users doesn't mean bigger security holes!

Answer (score 3):

Your APPLICATION should certainly have separate user ids and passwords for each user. Given that, there's no reason for the application to have multiple user ids when it talks to the database. As long as the application's security is implemented correctly, there's no gain from having multiple DB user ids.

Giving each user his own DB user id would surely be a gigantic pain because it would likely involve all sorts of special cases and exceptions. For example, to log in to your application, the application would have to validate the user's id and password. How will it do that if the user doesn't have access to the password table? But if anything needs to be protected from unauthorized access, it's the password table. So you'd have to use one userid to do the login, then take that away and give a different userid. It's likely that there are other tables that a given user might be allowed to access in one context but not in another. The accounting department likely needs to see total amounts paid in salaries for the year, but maybe they can't see individual employee's salaries. Employees may be able to access data about their own benefit, but not that of other employees. Etc.

The only exception I can think of to this would be if you allowed some sort of generic access to the database. To take the most extreme case, if you had a screen where the user can type in an arbitrary SQL query which you would then execute. In that case, you could theoretically have the application analyze the query and attempt to apply security rules, but that would require your application to embed an awful lot of knowledge about SQL. In that case you'd be better to give each user his own DB user id and putting the security rules into the database engine.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: Before the internet, yes.  After the internet: nobody does it, but it is still perfectly acceptable.

Common practice in the internet age is to consider your application to be the user, and to give that application a login.  The only actual benefit is some performance boost from connection pooling.  The perceived but illusory benefit is security.

Understanding the security angle requires the realization that all security in the end resolves down to who can read and write from what tables, rows and columns.  To see how this works, consider a user who is authorized to manipulate a highly secure table, and another user who cannot even see that table.  The less privileged user successfully manages a SQL injection attack attempting to wipe out the secure table, it fails because the Database prevents access by that user to that table.

The takeaway is that there is no technical reason to use a single login except if connection pooling is important.   Databases are very poorly understood by many internet age programmers so explaining how to use their built-in security is an uphill battle against many pre-conceived and incorrect ideas.